# PHP how be sure to catch all exceptions

Tags: php, class, exception

Suppose I have some code that uses `try{...} catch() { ... }` blocks. Within the tried code, there are various non-trivial third party objects (or maybe other data).

Often these third party objects will throw their own third party exceptions; how can I be sure to catch these without knowing what these exceptions are actually named?

With various third party objects and methods in various parts of the code, is there a relatively quick way of catching *all* exceptions thrown for further investigation?

**Detailed Usage Example** (Stripe has numerous Exception cases)

```
$someObject = new \someNamespace\someClass();
try {
    $x = $someObject->someFunction($someData); 
    $y = $stripeObject->StripeProcessing($x);
}
catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $ex) {
        // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught
        error_log("Stripe Card Error: ".$ex->message);
        $message = "There was a card error: ".$err['message'];
    } 
catch (\Stripe\Error\RateLimit   | 
    \Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest | 
    \Stripe\Error\Authentication |   
    \Stripe\Error\ApiConnection  |  
    \Stripe\Error\Base $ex) {
        $message = "There was a Stripe error: ".$ex->getMessage();
        error_log("Stripe Other Error: ".print_r($ex,true));
    } 
catch( \someNamespace\GiggityException |
    \someNamespace\GiggityNewMexicoException){
    error_log("Family Guy! ".print_r($ex,true));
    }
catch (Exception $ex){
    error_log("Elvis has died! ".print_r($ex,true));
}
```

Could result in:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SomeDistributor\SomeClass\Exception: connection() failed. ...etc...etc...

So above has a bunch of Exceptions to catch, from two namespaces, as well as the general `Exception` at the end; While the code reactions to all of these are very similar; I still seem to need to know the name of each and every Exception class thrown and have these manually coded in;

## So, is there a way of catching ALL possible exceptions in one place?

(Before then differentiating and branching how to handle specific ones, as needed)

I'm sure the solution to this is vey simple but I can't find liteature on this (d'oh; *I have since found literature*).

Comment: may be worth looking here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php - I've seen Symfony log errors well, might be worth checking their source

Comment: @treyBake thanks. I'm not sure I want to extend the standard basic class, if the standard `Exception` catches all uncaught Exceptions anyway, that's great, if not, I don't think extending it will help?

Comment: Depends - you can do a simple extension of the class to set a hard-value for log location and just call your new "custom" class

Comment: @treyBake no, sorry, you are correct. I found some literature that covers this: ALL exceptions extend the basic class, so yes you are correct. Thanks :-)

Comment: No problemo! Glad I could be of some help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This website](https://rollbar.com/guides/php-exception-handling/) states:

> The simplest way to catch exceptions is through the use of a generic try-catch block. Because exceptions are objects, they all extend a built-in Exception class (see [Throwing Exceptions in PHP](https://rollbar.com/guides/php-throwing-exceptions)), which means that catching every exception thrown is as simple as type-hinting the global exception object, which is indicated by adding a backslash in front:

> ```
> try {
>   // ...
>   } catch ( \Exception $ex ) {
>     // ...
>   }
> ```